# Is XHR allowed within web-worker in PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

Environment: Cordova 2.9.0, iOS (Xcode 4.6.3 iPad 6.1 Simulator and iPad 3 running iOS 6.1.3)

I am trying to separate out the processing of loading another file into a web-worker.  The file I am loading is part of the application (meaning it is in the same domain).

The following code works fine when NOT run in a web-worker: (*url* is of the form "/db/file.json")

```
function loadXMLDoc(url, successCallback) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (xmlhttp.status==200 || xmlhttp.status == 0)) {
        successCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

NOTE: *status* is always 0 when using cordova.  *status* is 200 when not using cordova.

When I separate this code into a web-worker the responseText comes back empty.

I removed phoneGap and verified that the code above worked with and without a web-worker.

Is it possible to use XHR in a web-worker within phoneGap/cordova?

Answer (score 4):

You will likely want to check that your server properly supports Cross Origin Resource Sharing. There are some handy resources for this, such as [CORS Enabled](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled), by the W3C.

When you run this without Cordova, you're likely actually loading a page from a server, such as `http://www.myserver.com/index.html`, but when you run it from Cordova, you're actually running `file:///somedirectory/www/index.html`. This means that if you attempt to use an ajax request to access information from `myserver.com`, it is on a different domain, and if not properly set up, the browser will reject the response.

The most important thing you can do is enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. This requires adding a new header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` who's value is `*`

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can solve it by change the way to load the file.

1. Forget XMLHttpRequest, because do not work with `file://` protocol.
2. Change the extension of the file from .json to .js
3. Set you JSON object into a variable. Ej. `var myJson = { "a":123,"b":789 };`
4. Load your JS file into your HTML. `<script src="db/file.json"></script>`
5. Read you data in JavaScript. Ej. `console.log(myJson);`

Comment: I'm seeing `file:` XHR requests work and posted an answer that reflects this...it's worth noting I posted the answer and suggest using xhr for local files simply because the Filesystem APIs (cordova-plugin-file) aren't available in workers and this is the only workaround I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes XHR does work for local files with cordova version 6.0.0 (cordova-ios version 3.x) **in workers** with the default iOS 9.2 UIWebView and (oddly) XMLHttpRequests work for the `file:` protocol (unlike pretty much all other browsers). *While I assume this is true across all the cordova implementations I haven't yet tried them all myself.* As mentioned the `status = 0` but both `load` and `error` handlers fire and `responseType` affects the `response` (xhr2) **all as-expected**. Unfortunately all of the File System APIs are not accessible so this makes for a peculiar/hacky way to access local files ([related bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10492)).

note: experimenting with update to cordova-ios version to 4.0 and WKWebView version 1.0.2-dev (still cordova version 6.0) and `file:` urls no longer work.

Comment: Enable file:// url access using this plugin I published. https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix