# Can anybody give me an example how to call a CORS enabled web service from web worker in Phonegap (iOS)?

Tags: cordova, web-worker

I want to call a Cors enabled Restful web service from my cordova iOS app within web worker.Cordova use to load the web app using file:// protocol and the web service is https:// so both the origins are different.I want to know whether it is possible or not?If so can anybody give me an example.

Comment: Of course is it possible in Cordova with proper settings in config.xml. But you gotta be more precise with your question by posting atleast your code that you have tried to help you out

Comment: I have posted my code in the given link.Can you please suggest why i getting the error "Failed to load resource: Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342534/calling-a-rest-api-from-web-worker-in-phonegap-xcode

Comment: Have you installed cordova whitelist plugin in your app to make AJAX calls? Also check the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154884/phonegap-jsonp-error-404-not-found-on-call/37318284#37318284 to include required setting in config.xml

Comment: Yes it's installed there.If i Copy the same code into the main thread then the code is working perfectly without any issues.Only from within the web worker it's not working and getting this error "Failed to load resource: Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".The following codes are included in my config.xml file: 
<access origin="*" /> <allow-intent href="http://*/" /> <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />.And the restful web service which i am calling is CORS enabled.I disabled cors in the server but it didn't helped thanks.

Comment: If you are using WKWebview, web worker will not work with CORS. Check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496239/is-xhr-allowed-within-web-worker-in-phonegap-cordova It may help.

Comment: I want to thank you for giving your valuable time.Sir i disabled CORS in the server but it didn't help.If i call a web service which is not restful and not CORS enabled then i can get the response successfully from my web worker.But the problem is i am unable to call rest api's whether its CORS enabled or disabled.Thanks

Comment: I m still not getting to understand what you exactly mean by web worker. Could you post your code so that i can test here?

Answer (score 0):

From Web worker we cannot directly call a CORS enabled api.But If you are deploying your hybrid app for iOS we can achieve this.There is a class called NSURLProtocol, Using its life cycle method this can be easily achieved.Thanks.